# Is there a way to monitor a carousel for a specific className, and change a different component when the class changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React SPA and have an interesting request from the client. They would like to be able to change the site (body) background image based on which slide in a carousel is active. I am using react-alice-carousel, but can't figure out how to monitor which slide has the class __active. When the slide changes (either on user interaction [click, swipe, tap, etc], it uses the className __active to toggle CSS which, in turn, displays different slides.

I have not tried anything that came even remotely close to working. I am still new to React, so hoping there is some "easy" solution.

Carousel Code:

```
<ul class="alice-carousel__stage">
    <li class="alice-carousel__stage-item" style="width: 715px;">
        <!-- Slide content here -->
    </li>
    <li class="alice-carousel__stage-item __active" style="width: 715px;"> <!-- See __active class here -->
        <!-- Slide content here -->
    </li>
    <li class="alice-carousel__stage-item" style="width: 715px;">
        <!-- Slide content here -->
    </li>
    <li class="alice-carousel__stage-item" style="width: 715px;">
        <!-- Slide content here -->
    </li>
    <li class="alice-carousel__stage-item" style="width: 715px;">
        <!-- Slide content here -->
    </li>
    <li class="alice-carousel__stage-item" style="width: 715px;">
        <!-- Slide content here -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the second element has class .__active. When the active slide changes (either via autoplay, user interaction, etc), the class moves to the correct slide. It can skip from any slide to a different one, and both forwards or backward.

The long story is that I need to somehow monitor the carousel and when that classname moves to a new element, I need to pull a prop from the new "active" element and pass it to a completely different component as a prop/state change.

In other words:

On active slide change, take the value of bgSrc prop on the active slide, and pass it to another component in the view to use as the background image.

Thanks for any help! I have been struggling to find a solution on my own!

**edit**
To simplify it more:
In reactjs, how can I monitor an element for a className change and fire a function when change is detected?

Comment: What aspect of the `li` or its contents will give you a `key` to allow you to select an image for the background?

Comment: Ok, I see you have edited to include, can you add the HTML for one slide with bgSrc included. Also does it need to use react? Or is vanilla JS ok?

Comment: @Bibberty Good question.

react-alice-carousel is actually a "content carousel". The image is being applied to a child of the li via a prop. I was thinking that simplifying the question to be focused on "is there a way to monitor for a class change, on change, if the className __active is present on li, pull the prop bgSrc from the child element, and pass it to a sibling/parent/aunt/uncle/second-cousin-once-removed-on-my-mothers-side-so-it-isnt-really-family-but-exists-on-the-same-page.

Also, adding a "simplified" question to the bottom of the original

Comment: Take a look here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alice-carousel, in particular take a look at the events : `onSlideChange` and `onSlideChanged` I think that is best way for you to approach this one.

Comment: Thanks! I had played around with those both but couldn’t figure out how to pass prop data from inside the active slide in a way that allowed me to use it in other places. I was considering set it to localStorage, but would really prefer to find a fully react way of solving it!